# Cannot add general block header arguments in org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, javascript

While I'm learning javascript following a book, I Like to take notes with org-mode. I use [Indium](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/Indium) and followed [this instructions](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-js.html) to handle it working

It works well, and I get my work done, interacting with browser, and getting great notes and structure about code, following exercises ...

But I need to type on every src block the session:

```
#+begin_src js :session "*JS REPL*"
console.log("calimero");
#+end_src
```

I tried to add, this at the begining of the file but not work:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:js :session "*JS REPL*"
```

or

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:js :session *JS REPL*
```

or this after the line of the section title:

```
* my title
 :PROPERTIES:
 :header-args: :session *JS REPL*
 :END:
```

or

```
* my title
 :PROPERTIES:
 :header-args: :session "*JS REPL*"
 :END:
```

or even scaping the `* "\JS REPL\*"`, but nothing works. I only get this error:

```
/private/var/folders/zs/t9wnzpqj2bdgjjgjwb8pqxc80000gn/T/babel-PdF5nq/js-script-46M5ix:1
require('sys').print(require('sys').inspect(function(){
               ^

TypeError: require(...).print is not a function

at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/zs/t9wnzpqj2bdgjjgjwb8pqxc80000gn/T/babel-PdF5nq/js-script-46M5ix:1:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Comment: First, try setting the session name to a string without whitespaces - maybe `:session jsrepl`. Second, did you refresh your local settings? Try `C-c C-c` on the property line or save the file and call `revert-buffer`.

Comment: This was the point, thanks @dangom

Comment: @dangom Please convert your comment to an answer. @ anquegi: Please accept dandom's answer. This marks this question-answer-pair as done.

Answer (score 1):

First, set the session name to a string without whitespaces, maybe `:session jsrepl`. Second, refresh your local settings - either by calling `C-c C-c` with the cursor above the property line, or save the file and call `M-x revert-buffer`.